# Implement Server Side Rendering to existing ReactJS app (frontend) and Nodejs app (backend)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have a Reactjs web app that is using Nodejs backend (two seperate apps/repositories). I want to implemented SSR to improve SEO and overall performance of my app. However I am not sure what is the best practice here. I have read some guides and most of them suggested nextjs, but I'm not really sure how that would affect deploy and so on.
Is there a way I can implemented SSR to my existing backend? Or should I do some changes to my front-end instead?

Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you use NextJS?

Comment: @MoussaBistami are there any problems migrating from React project to NextJS? Also how does the deploy work? Do I have to use vercel?

Comment: You're not forced to use anything also I doubt migrating would be an issue so just go ahead and try to add next js because Its the best to handle SSR. Good luck.